# Why is jest throwing `Error: "toString()" failed`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

When I try to run my jest test suite in my react app, it spits out this error:

```
Error: "toString()" failed
    at stringSlice (buffer.js:558:43)
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:631:10)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:601:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/andrew/Documents/wise-fox/The-App/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js:38:65)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/home/andrew/Documents/wise-fox/The-App/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js:64:1189)
    at /home/andrew/Documents/wise-fox/The-App/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js:64:1419
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/andrew/Documents/wise-fox/The-App/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js:64:1100)
    at Object.worker (/home/andrew/Documents/wise-fox/The-App/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/worker.js:64:46)
```

I even checked out to a handful of previous git snapshots, and the same error still occurs even though it didn't spit out this error before.

This error is not very helpful, and I'm not sure where the problem could lie. Any help in just knowing what to try next would be greatly appreciated.

React 16
Linux Elementary OS

Edit:

One of the failing tests.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Header from '../../components/Header/Header';

let wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallow(<Header />);
});

test('should render Header correctly', () => {
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: Can you at least show your failing tests? Almost impossible to answer otherwise

Comment: Sure, I can do that. Just a sec...

Comment: They're all shallow render with .toMatchSnapshot()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the problem was that I needed to run webpack before jest worked properly. Not sure why, but that was what worked.